# How to fill an Icon with custom image in next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, icons, tailwind-css

In my Next js 13 and tailwind project i want to have a chat/messagener icon that should be filled with image of my own choice. I have tried to use lucide react messanger icon and it accepts a fill prop however it only allow the hex color values to be filled but i want to fill that icon with either the image from my public folder or an image URL so can we achieve this ?                              import { MessageCircle } from 'lucide-react';

`

I tried to have a chat icon with a background image that doesn't go out of the boundary of chat icon however it doesn't happen and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Not sure about react libraries, but if you want to accomplish this using simple svg and css, you might wanna look into svg clip paths.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure you can directly fill an icon imported from a library like `lucide-react` with an image as the way i understand it you can only change size,color,strokeWidth,absoluteStrokeWidth.

I would probably just do it with React & Tailwind

```
const ExampleChatIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg className="w-10 h-10" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      {/* Define your mask */}
      <defs>
        <mask id="mask">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
          {/* This path defines the shape of your chat icon. It's filled with black to indicate the masking area. */}
          <path
            d="M50 10a40 40 0 1 0 0 80 40 40 0 0 0 0-80zm0 72a32 32 0 1 1 0-64 32 32 0 0 1 0 64zm-16-48h32a4 4 0 0 0 4-4v-8a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H34a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v8a4 4 0 0 0 4 4z"
            fill="black"
          />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      {/* Apply the mask to the image */}
      <image
        href="/your_path/image.jpg" // The image path
        width="100"
        height="100"
        mask="url(#mask)"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default ExampleChatIcon;
```

This example creates an SVG chat icon, fills it with the image you put in image “/your_path/image.jpg“.

You may also want to have the SVG part in a seperate file and import it to keep your codebase cleaner and more readable.

Hope this helps!